# Can player on different platforms play Bloons TD 6 in a co-op?

Tags: steam, ios, bloons-td-6

Say, can a user who purchased Bloons TD 6 on Steam for macOS play in a co-op with another user who purchased Bloons TD 6 on iOS? Or do all users need to be on the same platform (say all on Steam, or all on iOS), to be able to play in a co-op, which in my case would mean that one of the 2 would need to purchase the game again on another platform?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can. Bloons TD 6 is pretty standardised amongst platforms, unlike previous titles, supporting full cross-platform compatibility, including co-op and transferring your saves and profile from Mobile to PC and vice-versa.

Comment: I can confirm this is correct. I frequently play this game cross-platform.

Answer (score 0):

According to [This](https://steamcommunity.com/app/960090/discussions/0/1639790664936217137/) yes you can, you just need the invite code

Comment: Thank you for chiming in, but that answer is about saving the game state on one platform  and being able to continue on another platform. I am asking whether it is possible play with other players (co-op / multiplayer), where different players are are on different platforms.

Comment: Sorry about that, was a little tired then I guess lol. If you want to give it a shot with me, I might be able to attempt to join a match with you, I have it on iOS, just need to update

Comment: @avernet I’m ready to give it a go as long as you have BTD6 on a different platform than iOS. Just let me know if you want to try, just give me a code and I’ll join you.